# change a value in a file

Tags: shell-script, cron, scheduling

I have a configuration file that some of its lines is like below:

```
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 0-5
# Default:
DebugLevel=3
```

I want to change the 3 at DebugLevel to 5 at 2 AM then after for example 2 hours at 4 AM it change back to 3 again. how can I do this? with crontab or script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sed` to change the value at given time with cron:

To change `DebugLevel=3` to `DebugLevel=5` at 2am every day and then change back `DebugLevel=5` to `DebugLevel=3` at 4am every day, add following lines to your cron with `crontab -e`

```
0 2 * * * sed -i 's/DebugLevel=3/DebugLevel=5/g' file.conf
0 4 * * * sed -i 's/DebugLevel=5/DebugLevel=3/g' file.conf
```